# Login using OpenID delegate fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login, authentication

I just tried to login on another computer using my OpenID provider.

I use the delegate feature that lets me specify a URL, e.g. `http://example.org/daniel-beck-id`, and the document at that URL delegates authentication to my OpenID provider (MyOpenID in my case) using HTML tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="openid.server"
      href="https://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate"
      href="http://example.myopenid.com">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This has always worked for years, but today I got the following error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider
>   No OpenID endpoint found

When logging in using `example.myopenid.com` instead, it works, redirects me to MyOpenID to log in, and then wants to create a new account, of course. So that's not a solution, but proves that the OpenID provider works.

For some reason, the delegation of authentication fails.

Comment: Try using OpenID 2 instead of OpenID, given that OpenID is quite old it probably got removed. [Example](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a partly broken update of our OpenId library. This update has been reverted for now. See [No OpenId endpoint found wordpress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148929/no-openid-endpoint-found-wordpress/148938#148938) on Meta Stack Overflow for some more info.